# where is my apk installed on my device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created and installed android app.

I uses sqlite. I want to view its DB via "DB editor" app.

However I cannot find my app folder neither on the internal memory nor on the external card.

Comment: Data is saved in protected app-specific storage, to access it with another app you need root permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Databases are stored in `/data/data/my.package.name/databases/`. But this directory is protected, so only the app itself and *root* have access to this location. Without rooting your device, you won't have a chance to edit the database.

Comment: Actually `adb shell run-as` will at least let you copy a database from a device to, say, external storage for download. And it's not out of the question that you could run the device's own `sqlite3` shell via `run-as`, though I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

There is new support using IntelliJ 13 to view the database right from the IDE.  I assume this is also available in the most recent builds of Android Studio.  I've never used ADT so I can't comment if there is a similar feature in Eclipse.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/intellij-idea-13-eap-and-android-sqlite-database/